Releasing Version 2.2 with False Positive FLS Violations document
We have a scenario related to our app’s release cycle on AppExchange, and I need some guidance to handle the situation efficiently.
Background:

We have already released two versions of our Non-CPQ product on AppExchange:

Version 2.0: Submitted for security review, passed, and was listed on AppExchange.

Version 2.1: Released as a direct upgrade to 2.0 on AppExchange without another security review.


Current Situation (Version 2.2):

We are now preparing to release version 2.2, which includes some enhancements in functionalities. However, during internal testing with CheckMarx and PMD analyzer, we encountered a few false positive FLS update violations related to dynamic objects.

Detailed explanation in this post: Force.com code Scanner Portal Inability to Track FLS Checks on Dynamic Objects


Our Concerns:

We do not want to go through a full security review again, as it could be costly and time-consuming.

We are planning to document these false positives in a detailed report, explaining why they do not pose actual security risks.

We want to list version 2.2 as an upgrade to version 2.1 on AppExchange.


Questions:

How should we proceed with listing version 2.2 on AppExchange while avoiding the need for a full security review?

How do we submit the false positive documentation alongside the new version to ensure transparency with the AppExchange team?

Has anyone faced rejections or issues during AppExchange listings due to such false positives in the past? What’s the best way to handle them without triggering another security review?

Will the existence of these false positives automatically flag our new version for a full security review, even though we’ve already gone through the process for version 2.0?


I appreciate any advice on how to handle this situation smoothly. We aim to release version 2.2 without a full security review but still ensure the Salesforce team is aware of the false positives and understands they don’t pose a real threat.
Thanks in advance for your help!
